# Mailgun not sending and returning 'invalid version' error

Tags: javascript, email, reactjs, mailgun

Followed the docs for mailgun and have this code inside a function:

obviously edited out details for now

```
 sendEmail: function(){
    var api_key = 'key-XXXX';
    var domain = 'XXX';
    var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

    var data = {
      from: 'Mail Gun My Name <postmaster@sandboxXXXX.mailgun.org>',
      to: 'fake@email.com',
      subject: 'TEEEST',
      text: 'WAA WAA WEE WAA'
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
        console.log(body, 'body');
    });
  },
```

I then call it like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="Email" onClick={() => this.sendEmail()}/>
```

and for some reason the console is saying `invalid version`. I have put a console.log('here') at the top and it is definitely getting called so something funky going on inside mailgun...

Comment: Have you tried requiring mailgun at the top of your file, not inside the function?

Comment: @FabianSchultz nope. but interestingly when I move it to the top and try to save it I get an invalid verison error and the code does not run...

Comment: What version of mailgun-js are you using?

Comment: "mailgun-js": "^0.7.13",

Comment: @FabianSchultz I am getting the same error as here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/mailgun-vue and am now trying to build up in axion